# MegaRAID JBOD substitute

Tags: raid, hardware, storage, zfs, megaraid

It seems that certain MegaRAID chips don't support JBOD (unfortunately).

I've read online that to make these controllers act as a pass-through, I should configure the disks in RAID0.

What RAID0 settings do you recommend?

Comment: Which MegaRAID are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run this exact setup. MegaCli has a useful option called something like CfgEachDskRaid0 which will configure every disk on the array as raid0, ensuring a consistent configuration.

It's not true that it's impossible to hot swap disks with this setup, although it *is* clunky to do so (especially because MegaCli itself is hardly a paragon of usability), basically involves deconfiguring the old raid array and reconfiguring a new one every time you want to swap a disk.

Comment: This is still a bad solution for long-term ZFS use.

Answer (score 8):

Are you trying to use the card for a [software RAID solution like ZFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations)? Which controller are you using? If this is the case, using multiple RAID-0 logical drives will create an ugly situation if you need to swap a failed disk. The replacement drive will not be recognized until you reboot/reinitialize a new RAID-0 *array* containing the failed disk. It's not worth it. Use a proper HBA if possible, OR use the hardware RAID functions of the controller with ZFS (sometimes it makes sense).

Please refer to: [ZFS SAS/SATA controller recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations)

Comment: Exactly. I just finished to configure the 24 drives using megaraid's webios, a painful game. And yes, i will use ZFS. (i decided that 2 drives goes on raid 1 hardware for the os, the other are JBOD to ZFS). I'm using a 9280-4i4e, unfortunately i can't change it!

Comment: There's a big downside to configuring multiple RAID-0 arrays using the controller you're using (this also applies to Dell and HP RAID controllers). If you DO lose a disk, it's the same as losing a logical drive. Your replacement disk won't be recognized until your reboot. E.g. you won't have hot-swap capabilities. If you're interested in running a ZFS-based solution the right way, use one of the controllers I linked to in my earlier post.

Comment: understood and received that i can't go this way. Thanks.

Comment: [given the impossibility to change the controller], please look at this page: http://kb.lsi.com/KnowledgebaseArticle16511.aspx - maybe the red text is the solutions to my problems? =)

Comment: Probably not. It's just a downtime risk. The system will run just fine. It just means you'll need a reboot if you have to replace a failed disk. That's all.

Comment: I just hope more people read this. :(

Comment: @SvennDhert Why?

Comment: My first large server (100TB) has LSI MegaRAID SAS 9271-8i, with 34 raid0 disks (on each disk) with ZFS (raidz2), 1 disk hiccup put the system down for 48h, a replacement raidcontroller and disk where needed to save it. RAID 6 on the card or another card with JBOD and nobody would have noticed...

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this with 24 drives. Get a different controller. Anything based on the LSI 1068e (which is a bottom-of-the-line option for many Dell and IBM servers) will support JBOD. Dell calls it a SAS 6/iR and IBM calls it a ServeRAID BR10i.

Comment: Point is that, even paying, i can't change my controller. It's an OVH HG server. I contacted the support to see if they can do an exception, but i'm not optimist. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

**Untrue!** [Some of the MegaRAID cards](https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161496893/megaraid-3ware-and-hba-support-for-various-raid-levels-and-jbod-) (such as the raid controller that IBM rebrands as the M1015) do support JBOD passthru.

If you want to use JBOD mode I'd suggest these cards. Know a local IBM VAR? I'd recommend getting friendly with them - odds are they have a whole mess of these cards on hand.

Comment: Thanks, but i can't change my card! :(

Answer (score 1):

On our MegaRAID card we just make each drive its own raid-0 array, however we rarely have more than one drive in this configuration and I have no idea how well this scales.

Comment: yes, it's the same thing i'm doing - let's hope it to work on 24 drives :(

Answer (score 1):

Can`t you simply switch off the raid-controller in the BIOS?

Comment: I wouldn't see any disk at all if I did so!

Comment: I will try, but I'm dubios it will work... I will report it

Comment: disabling boot from card is useless.

Comment: An actual server where this would have worked would have been a Dell PowerEdge 2850 with PERC5i raid-controller. This raid-controller is being activated by a key. If the key is not present it will serve the disks as JBOD. Thus there is an option (if the key is present) to disable raid - and you will have JBOD instead. But that does not seem to be the case with "your" server.

Comment: It's a card inserted *on* the server, it's not an integrated stuff. thanks anyway.